# How to update progress dialog properly?

Tags: android, progressdialog, progress

In my app i'm displaying a list with a checkbox for each item. when user clicks on a button my app should import each checked item(Contact) to contacts app.
i am trying to show the user the progress(ItemIndex/TotalItems) + text of the current item (by using progress dialog).
Meanwhile my app is checking for each item (contact) it is already exist in the contacts app, and if so, a dialog will be displayed (this dialog is an activity - dialog themed) by using stratActivityForResult.
I've tried to use asynctask and all it does is to show a progress dialog with the first item and nothing more.
I also tried to use handler and it does the same thing.

can anyone help me?

EDIT:

```
int filesIndex=0;
ArrayList selectedFiles<String>;
startImport();

private void StartImport(final ArrayList<String> Files) 
{
  //checks if there's allready an existing item and if there is, call  displayConflict();

}




private void displayConflict(String file1, String file2) 
{
  startActivityForResult....//call an activity that looks like a dialog....

}



 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
  //use data....
  operate();//addnew / update / skip
  MoveNext();
}



protected void Movenext()
{
  filesIndex++; //------------> this is the step where I want to update ui with progressDialog....
  StartImport();
}
```

Comment: AsyncTask should be OK. Update the `ProgressDialog` at `onProgressUpdate` and call `publishProgress` as needed from `doInBackground`.

Answer (score -1):

In case, you are using **AsyncTask** the job is pretty simple. As you have to get the value in percent of your running job and pass it as an **int** using **publishProgress(progress)** where progress is the calculated value (status) of the ongoing task.

Then, override **onProgressUpdate** of **AsyncTask** which will take the value you passed using **publishProgress(progress)** and update your progressBar in this method.

You can refer the links below for more help :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7592623/1235555

[Example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/progressbar/android-progress-bar-example/)

Comment: well, that's the problem ...the heavy work is not inside the task it's in the activity and that's the way it has to be because I need to interact with the user . Do you have any other solution?