# Android sync HTTP request

Tags: android, http

I have no problems with async HTTP requests. Start service, make HTTP requests and receive broadcasts. Now I need execute a lot of HTTP requests and user must wait until they finished. Logic: "press button"-(Something blocking any touches)-"3-4 HTTP queries"-(Release). That the simple way to do this without intent broadcasts?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the question. To block the UI, see [`ProgressDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html). You still need to use async operations, as Android does not permit networking on the UI thread.

Comment: You could use an AsyncTask..

Comment: Thank you. Already all done before :-) Simple solution will be like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590555/android-asynctask-how-can-update-progressdialog-increment